# What is the difference between Parkside X20 Team and Parkside X20Team Limited Edition

Tags: powertools

I'm trying to find out what is the difference between the regular Parkside X20 Team tools and the so called "Limited Edition". I looked at the specs of several tools and didn't find any difference apart of the color scheme. The regular ones are green & black while the limited edition is trimmed in light-green & grey. The other difference is that the "limited edition" is 2-3 euros more expensive.

Any clues?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: My _guess_ is that the difference is the cool paint scheme and resting comfortably in the knowledge that you've paid more for the same thing. At least, that's the standard definition of _Limited Edition_. Usually it's nothing more than marketing.

Comment: If you go to the company's web site, they mention and show the "limited edition" tools but there is absolutely no mention of anything except the color scheme.  It certainly appears that the limited edition changes are limited to the colors.